# Different html pages based on Coptic Date via PHP

Tags: php, html, datetime

I am attempting to build a Lectionary in which the appropriate readings for the day would be displayed. I have written some existing code that displays the Coptic Date, however, I am having issues with the logic of displaying the appropriate .html files with the appropriate date.

Right now I am finding the Gregorian Date that attributes to the appropriate Coptic one but even that is not working. Looking for a way to use the Coptic Date with the logic below.

[A link that I was able to find regarding Coptic Date Calculations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19069658/get-today-coptic-date)

---

Logic: If the day is Tute 1 between 6 am and 6 pm, include tute1.html
else other.html

---

```
<?php
$DateTime = new DateTime();
$IntlDateFormatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'en_US@calendar=coptic',
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
    'America/Los_Angeles',
    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN
);
echo $IntlDateFormatter->format($DateTime); // Saturday, April 22, 2017 AD (Displays the current Gregorian Date)

echo str_repeat("&nbsp;", 30); 

$DateTime = new DateTime();
$IntlDateFormatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'en_US@calendar=coptic',
    IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM,
    IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
    'America/Los_Angeles',
    IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL
);
echo $IntlDateFormatter->format($DateTime); // Saturday, Baramouda 14, 1733 ERA1 (Displays the current Coptic Date)



//Tute 1
$day = date('d:m') ;
$time = date('H:i') ;
if (( $time > '6:00') && ( $day == '24:04') && ( $time < '18:00')); {$show = true ;}

if ( $show = true ) { include "test1.html" ; }
 else { include "test2.html" ; }

 //This date attribute is for testing purposes and does not reflect the actual Coptic date









?>
```